# Alfresco : how to show datatable in a form?

Tags: xml, forms, workflow, alfresco

I would like to know how can I display a datatable with several columns in a form?

This will be used in a workflow. The table will be filled with values and the user can add lines

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the below project 
Add the custom `datatable-property.ftl` at location `/org/alfresco/form/controls` and field properties like this :

```
<field id="mymodel:ListOfItems"  >
            <control template="/org/alfresco/form/controls/datatable-property.ftl" >
                <control-param name="config">
                        id, ID, number;
                        name, Item, text;
                        quantity, Quantity, number;
                        price, Price, currency;
                        paid, Was paid, radio, ["Yes", "No"];
                        features, Features, checkbox, ["JPEG", "MPEG", "MOV"];
                        color, Color, dropdown, ["Black", "White", "Blue"];
                        date, Date, date;
                </control-param>
                <control-param name="debug">false</control-param>
            </control>
        </field>
```

Alfresco Share's datatable property type widget. Displays data in datatable, having data saved as JSON inside text property.

This property control gets stored JSON string inside text property and displays JSON object in yui's datatable wiget. On every change of datatable content, control logic updates JSON string and that is saved on document upon meta-data Save.

It's got read and read/write mode, depending on user privileges and current view mode. This control can be applied to any text field on document.

please find the [DataTable Project](https://github.com/msvoren/alfresco-datatable-property) this may help you.